# Visual Studio > Google Chrome : open new window instead of new tab

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, google-chrome

I use Chrome as my default browser in Visual Studio 2010.

Whenever I debug a web app if there are any existing instances of Chrome open then VS automatically creates a new tab on that instance.

Does anyone know if it is possible to force VS open completely new window instead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know this is a bit of a late update, but I found a better way than with a registry hack.

When selecting browse with in visual studio you can set up a new shortcut to Chrome with arguments to open in a new window. (based on lysergic-acid's answer)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the solution you're looking for, as it's pretty "violent".

https://superuser.com/questions/166479/force-chrome-to-open-new-pages-in-new-window-not-tab-when-opened-from-a-progra

Basically, the technique is to replace how the windows shell is opening a new http link in the browser.

Under the registry key: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command

You need to change the command that will look similar to this:
"C:\Users\Lior\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1"

into this:

"C:\Users\Lior\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window "%1"