# VS used to open browser in new tab, now opens new browser

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've been updating to the latest version of Visual Studio Preview and I think a setting has been changed.

When I start debugging an ASP.NET web app in Visual Studio 2017 15.7.0 Preview 4, VS opens a new browser.

I've had a similar issue before and it was a setting. This time it's not that setting. As you can see below, my Chrome debugging is already unchecked.
[image]

I'm also aware of the check box to "Launch Browser" under Project -> Properties.

If I uncheck that no browser is opened. The previous behavior which I really liked was to open a new tab in my default browser i.e. Chrome.

How do I restore that behavior? I'd like VS to automatically open a new tab in Chrome and if I have no browser open, only then it should open up a new browser.

Comment: “Open in new Tab instead of new browser” sounds like a browser setting instead of a VS setting?

Comment: I don't think it's a browser setting. If I click a link in an email or a website, it always opens in a new tab. Maybe more telling is the fact that if I close the new browser window Visual Studio opens when I start debugging, it stops debugging. Clearly, the browser window and the debug process are linked.

Comment: You mention VS 2017 15.7.0 Preview. Are you saying that this unexpected new-window vs new-tab with Chome behavior began when you upgrade your VS 2017 from a previous (say, 15.6) version to the 15.7 Preview 4?

Comment: @Jazimov I believe you're right. I used to always get a new tab in an open Chrome browser whenever I started a debug session. Now, it looks like it's opening a new browser. I suspect this is a setting somewhere which the new 15.7.x activates by default.

Comment: Can you please ***check*** the "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge, and IE)" option and then let me know what happens? You mention that you unchecked an option above but it seems that you are referring to the "Launch Browser" checkbox.

Comment: @Jazimov It’s already unchecked - see image in original post.

Comment: I am asking you to check the option, not uncheck it. I have a reason for asking you to try this--but I want to know the results first. Thanks.

Comment: @Jazimov Sorry! I misread what you were saying. Let me try and get back to you shortly.

Comment: @Jazimov When I check it, it continues to open a new browser.

Comment: OK, I was hoping for a different outcome. Starting with all VS 2017 RC 1--it attaches to Chrome for ASP.NET debugging sessions using the remote debugging protocol (bit.ly/2qZL5JK), (bit.ly/2HTLCHu). I suspected that any time VS launches a Chrome instance using the remote debugging protocol, that Chrome will always present a new window. While that may be true (I've not yet been able to confirm this), it doesn't explain why you could previously debug in Chome using VS 2017 and see new tabs instead of a new Chrome window...

Comment: I think solutions mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716494/stop-visual-studio-from-launching-a-new-browser-window-when-starting-debug) can help you.

Comment: I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841315/visual-studio-google-chrome-open-new-window-instead-of-new-tab) might help you. OP in the linked post wants to open in new window instead of tab, but you can follow the same process and replace new window with new tab

Comment: I'm really perplexed here. The original behavior for me was this: I'd simply start the debug process which would open a new tab in my already open browser. Closing that tab would NOT stop the debug process. None of the solutuions suggested here restore that behavior. If I uncheck "Launch Browser", then starting the debug process doesn't open anything i.e. a new browser or a new tab. This is not the behavior I want. I do want a new tab opened, just not a new browser.

Comment: @Sam I played around with the settings and unchecking `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Stop debugger when browser window is closed` seems to do the job (at least on my end).

Comment: @KingKerosin You've got the answer my friend!!! Could you please post it as the answer so that I can accept it? I'd like you to get credit for this. I also want it show up as the answer so that others can benefit from it. Thank you very much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Sam I've added an answer. I just confirmed that `15.7.1` has the same issue opening new instances without this setting unchecked.

Comment: @KingKerosin Accepted your solution as the answer. Don’t know why the Microsoft team would mess with things that are perfectly fine!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

After updating Visual Studio to the latest version `15.7.0` I ran into the same issue. In my case each time I debugged my project it opens up two new instances of `Chrome`.
As this was not annoying enough, each time I was moving the window to my second screen, the debug-session stopped immediately.

I've searched the Visual Studio options for `browser` and found a setting called

> Stop debugger when browser window is closed

which could be found under `Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects`. I unchecked this setting and et voilà the next debug-session started as tabs in my already running browser-instance.

As I am not sure if this is a bug introduced with this Visual Studio version, this may change again in any next release. So this setting may be reverted in case of any unexpected behavior.

**Update**

Seems like version `15.8.5` still has this issue/behavior.

Comment: Version `15.7.2` - the problem is still reproducable

Comment: A solution for Visual Studio Professional 2017 `15.7.5` too!

Comment: HAPPY DANCE!  Works with Visual Studio 2022 (17.0.4)