# Visual studio 2017 debug opens new browser

Tags: debugging, browser, visual-studio-2017, vs-community-edition

I have visual studio 2017 community with latest update , when i want to debug any project it will open a new browser window instead of opening a new tab , i have searched everyone mentioned to disable javascript debugging , but this one won't help me and still opens with new browser window i have tested on chrome, firefox ,edge , all of them are the same , also i have noticed when i drag the opened browser to main chrome browser the debug will stop also, i have attached debugging options ,[image]

it is bout three weeks and got nothing to solve this , any ideas ?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50246424/815938

Comment: thank you saved my life i don't know why i did not see this on web , may thanks , should i delete my question ?

Comment: Glad that I can help. You can keep it, 'cause I feel it can help others in searching for this issue. I will close it as exact duplicate.

Comment: Uncheck here Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Web Projects: "Stop debugger when browser window is closed".

Comment: Many thanks dear , solved :)